# Rewrite /word/?q=term to /word/term

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have this in my htaccess currently:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?word/(.*)$ /word.php?$1 [L]
```

Which lets me visit a url for example `http://www.example.com/word/term` and my php script will do some dataabse work for the keyword `term`

But I am trying to add a search form which currrently goes to `http://www.example.com/word/?q=term` and my php script is doing DB lookups on `?q=term` rather than just `term`

My form action is going to `/word/` and my method is `get`

Can I add a rewrite to rewrite `/word/?q=term` to `/word/term`?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I add a rewrite to rewrite `/word/?q=term` to `/word/term`

You can add a rule before your other rule:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(word)/?$ /$1/%1? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^/?word/(.*)$ /word.php?$1 [L]
```